# vim: remove previous code indentation and convert to another

Tags: linux, vim, text-formatting, autoindent

I have a c project with multiple files (more than 100), the codes are written in [Whitesmiths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Whitesmiths_style) style, but I want to change them into [K&R style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) indentation. Is it possible to do using vim in an automated way ?

For example I have a emacs-lisp script to achieve this --

```
(progn 
  (find-file "{}") 
  (mark-whole-buffer) 
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil) 
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)) 
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil) 
  (save-buffer))
```

I was wondering if there is a similar trick that could be done with vim.

**Update:** I have found another nice tool called [astyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net), which supports auto-indentation for different languages (with a wide range of styles) as well.

Comment: Of note is [GNU Indent](http://www.gnu.org/software/indent/) which does this all by itself, and is well tested. Avoiding reinventing the wheel, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either pass all C files to the Vim executable `vim file1.c dir/file2.c`, or add them as arguments from inside Vim (see `:help file-searching`):

```
:args **/*.c **/*.h
```

Then, you can mass-edit them via `:argdo`. Vim has a built-in indenting mechanism, or it can use an external code formatter. Read up on the details at `:help C-indenting`.

Once you've configured the indent settings (`'cindent'`, `'cinoptions'`, etc.), you can apply all files via

```
:argdo execute 'normal! ggVG=' | update
```

(`ggVG` selects the entire buffer in visual mode, `=` then re-formats.)

Comment: You have the best Vim answers :) +1

Answer (score 4):

**man indent** *scroll scroll scroll*

```
   The Kernighan & Ritchie style is used  throughout  their  well-known  book
   "The  C  Programming Language".  It is enabled with the ‘-kr’ option.  The
   Kernighan & Ritchie style corresponds to the following set of options:

        -nbad -bap -bbo -nbc -br -brs -c33 -cd33 -ncdb -ce -ci4 -cli0
        -cp33 -cs -d0 -di1 -nfc1 -nfca -hnl -i4 -ip0 -l75 -lp -npcs
        -nprs -npsl -saf -sai -saw -nsc -nsob -nss
```

E.g.:

```
indent -kr source.cpp
```